# improving code and check for errors

Tags: vba, excel, search, excel-2010

This is the code, that i'm using, for every new search ,it creates a new sheet and the new sheet will be named after the searched word, but how do improve my code?Just a little info about this code that if the users adds asterisk before and after the word, it will do a wildcard search initially, passing everything to sheet2 but i have alter the codes to create a new search base on the searched word but also i am getting new errors. How should i check for error?

- If the user leaves a blank in the textbox, the program will stop the
  macro instead of creating a empty sheet.
- if the user adds asterisk in the search textbox, the program will
  create a new sheet just for the wildcard search

  ```
     strSearch = Application.InputBox("Please enter the search string")

     Worksheets.Add().Name = strSearch
     Set rg = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1).CurrentRegion                                       
     For a = 1 To rg.Rows.Count                                                                 
     Set rgF = rg.Rows(a).Find(strSearch, , xlValues, xlWhole)

    If Not rgF Is Nothing Then
    rg.Rows(a).Copy Sheets(strSearch).Range("A60000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

    Set rgF = Nothing
    End If
    Next a

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  ```

Comment: If the user enters `*Blah*`, what should be the sheetname be? Also what errors are you getting?

Comment: @SiddharthRout they would prompt me a error "Subscript without range" after using the code below.

Comment: Just to confirm if the user enters say "Sid" in the inputbox then it will create a sheet called "Sid"? and if the user enters "*Sid*" then it will prompt an error? and what if the user enters "*Sid" ? Again prompt an error?

Comment: @SiddharthRout Sorry i dont see a difference between the 1st and 2nd sid, but when i type in "*sid", it prompt invalid name for sheet error.

Comment: @SiddharthRout it's okay, i've done it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As far as there as some forbidden characters which could not be placed in Sheet name you need to do something like this:

```
strSearch = Application.InputBox("Please enter the search string")

if len(strSearch) > 0 then
    'add new sheet where in name we use the followings symbols
    '(X) instead of * asterisk
    '(Q) instead of question marks
    'and other are possible...
    Worksheets.Add().Name = replace(replace(strSearch, "*", "(X)"), "?", (Q))
else
    'if there isn't any string provided by user:
    'do nothing
end if
Set rg = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1).CurrentRegion       
'...the rest of your code
```

If user search for `*Blah?` you get sheet name as `(X)Blah(Q)`.